# Validate SFTP Put Operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysftp

I'm using pysftp 0.2.8 to put files on a remote SFTP host. I want to add validation to confirm the file was put on the remote SFTP host.

The put function on the pysftp.Connection object will raise the following errors

IOError – if remotepath doesn’t exist
OSError – if localpath doesn’t exist

[pysftp API Doc](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.8/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.put)

So that falls short for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Right now I'm validating by comparing the st_size of the local file with the st_size of the remote file, but this doesn't 'feel' right.

```py
local_file_size  = os.stat(processed_file).st_size        
remote_file_size = sftp.put(processed_file, confirm=True).st_size
   if remote_file_attributes.st_size != local_file_attributes.st_size:
      raise Exception('Discrepency between local file and remote file sizes. File might not have transferred, or only partially transferred.')
```

Is this a reliable means to check if a file was transferred? Would there be any reason to suspect the file could be off by a byte or more if it was transferred successfully?

Comment: Depends on which calls are being moved over the transport layer. `sftp` is expressive enough that a client can open with `O_APPEND` and write front-to-back (in which case everything would work)... or seek to the last byte, write it first, then jump back and write from the beginning.

Comment: More realistically, a client is perfectly able to open N different connections and copy a different subset of the file in each one, so there's no guarantee that the file is complete immediately after the last byte is written. On the other hand, for *many* folks that'll be true.